# What is the difference between these two ways of saving data in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

What is the difference between these two ways of saving data in CakePHP

```
$this->request->data['User']['status'] = 'Active';

$this->User->saveField('status', 'Active');
```

Comment: you cannot compare the two. for the first you should add $this->Model->save() for the question to make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->request->data['User']['status'] = 'Active';
```

It means you will call save() or saveAll() after. Those methods will check the validity of the data.

```
$this->User->saveField('status', 'Active');
```

There is no data validation and you need to set the $this->User->id before calling saveField.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that this line of code isn't actually saving any data:

```
$this->request->data['User']['status'] = 'Active';
```

It's just changing a field on that model.

If you were to update that field and then do `$this->User->save()`, you would save the entire model (including the field you just changed).

When you use `$this->Model->saveField(field,value)` you're actually updating the datasource with the new field value for the currently loaded model.

You may want to use `saveField()` in situations where you have not loaded all data fields and using `save()` will fail validation or overwrite existing values with empty/null values.